# cocoa: NSTextField with custom font, cursor out of wack

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstextfield

I have an `NSTextField` with a custom font set up in Interface Builder. When it loads, this is how it shows up:

[image: start]

When the user starts typing, the cursor moves correctly

[image: second]

And then when the user deletes the text it resets to the correct original position

[image: third]

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

try to enable the CG layer for the textfield and its superview

```
.wantsLayer = YES;
```

Comment: so then try to set the string to @" " and then back to @"" in the awakeFromNib, or somewhere